# Serialize/Deserialize arbitrary element value with Simple-XML

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

There's one particular element in my XML document that can hold any arbitrary XML data, or be empty (it is basically a cookie type of field, where the client can send any data they want, and the server sends it back).

How can I support this for both serialization and deserialization with the simple-framework? Basically I just want to deserialize the element from the client's request, what ever it may be, and then serialize it back to XML as part of the response. But I'm not sure what class I could use for this field, or if there's a way to write a converter for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can distinguish the type by element name you can use @ElementUnion like so.

```
@ElementUnion({
   @Element(name="x", type=X.class),
   @Element(name="y", type=Y.class),
   @Element(name="z", type=Z.class)
})
```

Other than that the standard class= attribute can be used.

Comment: Thanks for idea, but that doesn't work for me. I literally want to accept any valid XML inside this element, and I don't care about deserializing it to a particular class, I just want to be able to store it's data losslessly and serialize it base to XML in the response.